# What if I stopped time machine first backup?

Tags: backup, time-machine

yesterday I was doing the first big backup with Time Machine. About 600Gb. I know Time Machine does it first, the it will backup only changes to the original. Ok.

I stopped the backup by quitting my computer when it was at about 180Gb backed up. I though this morning it would have restarted the same backup from there. Instead, it seems it started a news one since it's saying 1Mb [counting] of 400Gb (not 600).

So, should I cancel it, erase form disk and start a new 'first' backup from zero and do not quit my mac until is finished?

Comment: If it backuped up 180 GB yesterday and continues with 400 today this seems to cover the whole 600 GB for one backup, doesn't it?

Comment: Maybe. I don't know. I would really like to better understand how time machine works. Official docs are not so in-depth. For example, based on my situation, say the next month I'll need a full recovery of my system/disk (maybe a new computer ok?) what is going to happen with thos 'partial' backups? Say I point the time to yesterday (the first 180Gb): what is going to happen? If I currently enter time machine, it's showing me the yesterday backups just as they where full backups, but they can't be full. Probably I'm not fully understanding the whole thing... But that's why I'm a little afraid.

Comment: The backup you started yesterday isn‘t partial, it just is still proceeding with the remaining 400 GB. This always takes a lot of time. Future backups will usually run within minutes.

Comment: ok thank you. I think you should add an official answer :)